# Combining Positive Lookahead and Negative Lookahead - Regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a simple regex in postgres 9.5 using `~`

I want to combine a positive lookahead and a negative lookahead. This is my Regex which is not working:

```
CHANGE.+(?=SHOES.+(?!NIKE))
```

Here is my [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/moxAHi/1) and below is an example of my issue:

**MATCH:**

```
CHANGE THE SHOES TO REBOOK.
```

**NOT MATCH:**

```
CHANGE OF SHOES TO NIKE AIRS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which only uses a single negative lookahead:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col ~ 'CHANGE.+SHOES(?!.*NIKE)';
```

If you want an exact answer to your question, see the response by @trincot.

Answer (score 0):

The `.+` after `SHOES` is greedy and so the `(?!` will only be checked at the end of the string where it is true (i.e. there is no `NIKE` there), and so there is no backtracking.

Instead do this:

[`CHANGE.+(?=SHOES(?!.*NIKE))`](https://regex101.com/r/EO4ef6/1)